# Analyse the contribution of a specific, concomitant condition

Tags: regression, medicine

I cannot think of an appropriate statistical test: I am conduction a retrospective chart review on patients. I'd like to see what a specific condition B (All patients have Condition A, several of them have ALSO condition B) contributes to various outcomes.

To visualize it a bit

......................| Death | Intensive care admission | Discharge to Rehab....

| Group A     |

| Group A+B   |

It feels odd to me to just calculate the calculate the OR. (which are between 1.7 and 3.4 with a CI >1).  But I cannot think of an appropriate regression analysis to answer this question.

Comment: Welcome to cv, Anthony! No need to apologize, but did you want to show a table here? Seems that you forgot the numbers (?) Since you are worried about your calculations - how did you calculate odds ratios (odds of what)?

Comment: THank you Ute, 

I indeed wanted to show a table - but just to emphasize the 2 groups. Didnt want to include numbers, but I certainly can if this would be helpful. 
I calculated the Odds ratio using a simple contingency 2x2 table:

...................Death....Survival
Group A...... 236.....10056
GroupA+B......44.....744

Comment: Sorry, thought it would show the table in a nicer way. 
Either way, I would love to check the contribution of the additionally (concomittantly) present condition B on Death, ICU admission, spinal cord injuries and some other outcomes. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, your comments clarify quite a bit :-) Could you try to include this in your question?

Comment: Why are you unhappy with odds ratio? I agree, it is somewhat weird to interpret - if this is the reason, what would be the best for you? Ratio of probabilities for certain outcomes?